# Disable button in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This code is working for me in normal view.

```
[disabled]="newSongs?.length<6"
```

I want set an extra otption for mobile view (xs).

```
[disabled]="newSongs?.length<2"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with some javascript.

In you component, listen to the event of screen changing (and set initial value on init):

```
public isXsView: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.isXsView = window.innerWidth < 360;
}

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.isXsView = window.innerWidth < 360;
}
```

Then in your view

```
[disabled]="(!isXsView && newSongs?.length<6) || (isXsView && newSongs?.length<2)"
```